# Click on a child div according to main title

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I have a div and within it several debts. In each div, I have a title, results and a final div to click on.
How do I make the click event in this final div according to a title search?

I have experience with WebDriver and PHP, but I've tried it all with the function By.xpath but no success.

Example: I need to click in `<div class="Link_Text "></div>` if it has the text "Race 19 Magic" in the `<div classe="RaceTitle "></div>`

How to?

`$driver->findElement(By.xpath(" XPATH_HERE "))->click();`

```
<div>
    <div class="races ">
        <div class="FixedRace ">
            <div class="RaceTitle ">Race 19 Magic</div>
            <div class="Link ">
                <div class="Link_Text ">See All</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="FixedRace ">
            <div class="RaceTitle ">8.57 Mega (Race 10)</div>
            <div class="Link ">
                <div class="Link_Text ">See All</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are the event handlers?  Basically you can check the text in xpath by using .text()... something like "//*[contains(text(), "your_text")]  Exactly what you need to click on is unclear though.  Does a script set event handlers to the divs?

Comment: @pcalkins Exactly. Find the main div that contains the text "Race 19 Magic", isolate this div and click on its respective div Link_Text

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following customized xpath as per your Example. Please let me know either it is working or not?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='See All']//parent::div[@class='Link ']//preceding-sibling::div[text()='Race 19 Magic']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To click the `<div>` with text as **See All** with respect to the `<div>` with text as **Race 19 Magic** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPath* 1:

  ```
  $driver->findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='RaceTitle ' and text()='Race 19 Magic']//following::div[1]/div[@class='Link_Text ' and text()='See All']"))->click();
  ```
- *XPath* 2:

  ```
  $driver->findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='RaceTitle ' and contains(., 'Race 19 Magic')]//following::div[1]/div[@class='Link_Text ' and text()='See All']"))->click();
  ```